# How to remove auto generated classes in jax-ws clients

Tags: soap, netbeans, jax-ws, webservice-client

I have a web service which I created with jax-ws in NetBeans. When I create the soap client from the wsdl file, Netbeans generates the mapping classes used for serialisation.

My problem is that I don't want them. I wrote them myself and they are used in other parts of the application. I tried everything to use my classes instead of the auto generated to send the SOAP message but with no success. 
The cumbersome solution would be to copy the data from one class to the other and then send the message, but my class has about twenty subclasses so I would like very much to skip this.

Comment: What about if you use the remote WSDL instead of local file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the JAXB [`episode`](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/reusing-generated-jaxb-classes.html) option which basically allows you to instruct JAXB to reuse classes in a package. You specify the desired packages in an *episode* file. "episode" is just a fancy name for a jaxb binding file and it's not very different from your regular jaxb config file. Your episode file would look something like this (bindings file excerpt courtesty of Blaise Doughan's blog)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <bindings version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
   <bindings scd="x-schema::tns"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Product">
    <schemaBindings map="false"/>
    <bindings scd="tns:product">
      <class ref="com.you.yourclass"/>
    </bindings>
   </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Save the file as a `.episode` file and configure in your Netbeans project like so. I assume here that you've run the **Create Webservice from WSDL** wizard in Netbeans

1. Right click on **Webservice** node within your project. Navigate to the **WSimport options** tab
2. Under the **Jaxb(xjc) options** frame, add the following

[image: Customize WSImport]

(where `myepisodefile.episode` refers to the episode file you created earlier. Make sure the file is available within your project)